# Can I make a QToolButton perform QLabel.setLayout(someLayout)? -- setting row height isn't working

Tags: user-interface, layout, pyside, updating

My only GUI experience is with java.swing. I'm using PySide to update which of two QGridLayouts are set to a QLabel depending on a button press, but the actual update isn't happening. Making a call to `self.update()` after lines 123 and 130 didn't work. Should I be using a repaint event or something?

```
def displaySimulator(self):
if self.sim_vis == True: pass
else:
    self.sim_vis = True
    self.graph_vis = False
    self.options.setLayout(self.simulator_settings)

def displayGraphing(self):
if self.graph_vis == True: pass
else:
    self.graph_vis = True
    self.sim_vis = False
    self.options.setLayout(self.graphing_settings)
```

Here's the [full code](https://gist.github.com/Aweeeezy/bf0bada7bb3d5959615c).

`----------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Also, the toolbar label at the top is way too big...

```
self.layout.setRowMinimumHeight(0,20)
self.layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(0,250)
self.layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(1,1000)
```

`setColumnMinimumWidth()` works fine but `setRowMinimumHeight()` doesn't seem to work at all. I'm still a little confused about how the size of QWidgets are affected by layouts, containers, and subwidgets...perhaps I need to adjust the size of the QLabel, `toolbar`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a QWidget instead of a QLabel for self.options. Does that change anything?

For the toolbar spacing, do addStretch() after you add the last widget to the layout, but note that if you use a layout in a toolbar, you lose the built-in capabilities for it to autosize and hide buttons in a "... more options ..." type thing.

Comment: Switching to a QWidget has no effect :/ 

`addStretch()` is a attribute of QBoxLayout...QGridLayout doesn't have it.

edit:
I'm not so concerned about the toolbar resizing because it's going to be 6 buttons in the (0,0) cell of the QGridLayout; for future projects, I would use QToolBar instead but I was having problems getting it to size properly...whatever my problem is now is probably the same problem as when I was using QToolBar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you name your object a toolbar I would actually make it a QToolbar. I would like to point out some styling points, because you said you were new.

import * is always bad for many reasons. You should know what you are importing and from where.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
```

Since you have a main GUI that you are running I would make that a QMainWindow. I would then add a menu bar and move some of your functionality to a file menu or edit menu.

This is just my style and how I like to do things

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class SimulatorWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """Application for running a simulator and displaying the resutls."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimulatorWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Simulator") # Main window

        # Properties
        self.main_menu = None
        self.simulator = None
        self.export_action = None
        self.settings_action = None
        self.exit_action = None


        self.initUI()
        self.initMenu()

        self.resize(600, 400)
    # end Constructor

    # Builds Simulator GUI
    def initUI(self):
        self.simulator = Simulator()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.simulator)

        self.addToolBar(self.simulator.toolbar)
    # end initUI

    def initMenu(self):
        """Initialize the menu bar."""
        menubar = self.menuBar()

        # ===== File Menu =====
        self.file_menu = menubar.addMenu('&File')

        # Export action
        iexport = QtGui.QIcon()
        self.export_action = QtGui.QAction(iexport, "Export", self)
        self.export_action.triggered.connect(self.export)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.export_action)

        # Separator
        self.file_menu.addSeparator()

        # Simulator Settings Dialog action
        isettings = QtGui.QIcon()
        self.settings_action = QtGui.QAction(isettings, "Settings", self)
        self.settings_action.triggered.connect(self.simulator.dialog.show)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.settings_action)

        # Exit action
        iexit = QtGui.QIcon('exit.png')
        self.exit_action = QtGui.QAction(iexit, '&Exit', self)
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.exit_action)

        # ===== Edit Menu =====
        self.edit_menu = menubar.addMenu('&Edit')

        self.edit_menu.addAction(self.simulator.run_action)

    # end initMenu

    def export(self):
        """Export the simulation file."""
        pass
    # end export
# end class SimulatorWindow


class Simulator(QtGui.QWidget):
    """Simulator display."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #Properties    
        self.toolbar = None
        self.dialog = None
        self.run_action = None

        # Layout
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # Graph
        stuff = QtGui.QLabel("<font color=red size=300>Graphing stuff</font>")
        stuff.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: rgb(50,50,50); font-size:250;}")
        stuff.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        graph = QtGui.QLabel("<font color=green size=250>Graph here</font>")
        graph.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: rgb(0,0,0); font-size:250;}")
        graph.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        graph.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(stuff)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(graph)

        self.initToolbar()
        self.initSettingsDialog()
    # end Constructor

    def initToolbar(self):
        self.toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()

        irun = QtGui.QIcon()
        self.run_action = QtGui.QAction(irun, "Run", self)
        self.run_action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.run_action)

    # end initToolbar

    def initSettingsDialog(self):
        """Initialize the Settings dialog."""
        self.dialog = QtGui.QDialog(self)
        self.dialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Dialog | QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.dialog.setLayout(layout)

        # Initialize the Widgets
        title = QtGui.QLabel("<font size=6>Simulator Settings</font>")
        num_sim = QtGui.QLineEdit("Number of simulations")
        num_trials = QtGui.QLineEdit("Number of trials (per learning phase)")
        network = QtGui.QComboBox()
        subject = QtGui.QComboBox()

        # Set the layout
        layout.addWidget(title, 0, 0, 1, 2, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(num_sim, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(num_trials, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(network, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(subject, 2, 1)
    # end initSettingsDialog

    def run(self):
        """Run the simulation."""
        pass
    # end run
# end class Simulator


def main():
    """Run the application."""
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = SimulatorWindow()
    window.show()

    return app.exec_()
# end main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: I tried changing the main class from inheriting a QWidget to a QMainWindow, but now my window displays nothing at all. Since the application was almost working completely before, I'll stick with inheriting from QWidget instead.

QToolBar works a lot better now. It fixed my QGridLayout cell size issue. I still can't get figure out how to update the display after setting the options QLabel or QWidget, neither makes a difference (see lines 74 & 75)
Here's my [updated code](https://gist.github.com/Aweeeezy/c99da0156bcab668ac71). I feel like there's something missing after lines 135 and 142

Comment: If you look in the code I posted I separated it into two different classes. One class is the QMainWindow that class holds the menu bar and the main widget. To get a QMainWindow to show something you have to setCentralWidget. The other class I made was the central widget called Simulator. The above code I wrote should run on python 3.X.